# Updating gradle for all projects

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio. I have updated gradle recently. However, every time I try to build a previously built project, I get a gradle prompt telling me to upgrade to the latest version of gradle.

Question is, is there a way for all android projects to be automatically updated to the latest version of gradle without the prompt? Clicking update now is tiresome. 
I am using Android Studio 3.1 with the March 22 Update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** you can't because **every project have its own Gradle Build**. And at the time you create your first project it is being created for your project separably taking reference from android studio for the latest android gradle build at that time. Now Gradle is being updated in android studio so whenever you open your first project it check whether your Gradle is latest or not and if not it always shows a prompt to update the gradle until you update it.

Comment: I am starting to think the same thing. Why can't there be a simple fix for everything. Cheers though.

Comment: if this answers your question mark as answer :) so that others can take benefit from it

Comment: For other users bothered by this minor annoyance, newer projects don't prompt for an update.

Comment: yes because when you created new project it build your gradle with latest version so there is no point to update gradle because it is already updated.

Comment: They still have not come up with a way to fix this on the fly

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Settings->Build,Execution,Deployment->Build Tools->Gradle and Select 'Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)'

and go to File->Project Structure->Project, set Gradle Version to 4.4 and Plugin version to 3.1.0

Comment: All these are set. Still the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check to your root project  file and update it with below classpath in android 3.1

dependencies {classpath com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1}
that new popup dialog inform you to about android new updates that you want to update in that your current project or not so don't worry about update dialog and neglect it.

Comment: But I wouldn't be able to take advantage of the update. I want the update. I just don't want to click apply every time I open a previously built project

Comment: so you have to update it once for the current project then it will not appear again . 
I think check you have slow internet connection that's why it will not updated so every time you open project that time that updated pop-up show

Comment: That makes no sense. I am on 4G. Anyway, I figured it out. You have no choice but to hit update. Newer projects don't give you the prompt